# MongoDB C++: Is mongocxx::pool thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

Do I have to manually lock mongocxx::pool while acquiring a connection?

i.e Is this safe? (example copied from Mongo website)

```
mongocxx::instance instance{};
mongocxx::pool pool {mongocxx::uri{}};

using mongocxx::pool::entry = std::unique_ptr<client, std::function<void (client*)>>

auto threadfunc = [](mongocxx::client &client, stdx::string_view dbname) {
    client[dbname]["col"].insert({});
}
// don't even bother sharing clients. Just give each thread its own,
std::thread([]() {
    // pool.acquire() returns a mongo::pool::entry type
    mongocxx::client *c= pool.acquire().get();
    threadfunc(*c, "db1");
    threadfunc(*c, "db2");
});

std::thread([]() {
    mongocxx::client *c = pool.acquire().get();;
    threadfunc(*c, "db2");
    threadfunc(*c, "db1");
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, `mongocxx::pool` is thread-safe. You may access it concurrently from multiple threads. However, the individual `mongocxx::client` objects returned from the pool are *not* thread-safe, nor are the subordinate objects like `collection` or `database` obtained from the `client` - you must not share them between threads.

Note also that your example (which is not copied verbatim from the website but is modified from one of the examples), contains a serious programming error.

This line:

```
   mongocxx::client *c= pool.acquire().get();
```

Will obtain a pool entry, then extracts a bare pointer from it. However, the pool entry will be destroyed at the end of the statement, causing the underlying `client` object to be returned to the pool, allowing another thread to potentially pick it up while you continue to use it.

You should write this as:

```
mongocxx::instance instance{};
mongocxx::pool pool {mongocxx::uri{}};

auto threadfunc = [](mongocxx::client &client, stdx::string_view dbname) {
    client[dbname]["col"].insert({});
}
// don't even bother sharing clients. Just give each thread its own,
std::thread([]() {
    // pool.acquire() returns a mongo::pool::entry type
    auto c = pool.acquire();
    threadfunc(*c, "db1");
    threadfunc(*c, "db2");
});

std::thread([]() {
    auto c = pool.acquire();
    threadfunc(*c, "db2");
    threadfunc(*c, "db1");
});
```

That way, each thread retains the pool entry until it is finished using it, at which point it will be automatically returned when the `unique_ptr` in `c` is destroyed.

Comment: @xcorat it is polite to upvote and/or accept the best answers to questions you have asked.

Comment: geez! I just read the answer :p (jk, but yeah, I just read it, thanks :)

Comment: And yeah, I ended up changing my code to exactly how you fixed it, and thought I edited the question, but I guess I hadn't. Thanks again!